# Number round down in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rounding

Is there any built-in way to round a number down no matter the decimals?

For example

```
<div>{{var / 3 | number:0}}</div>
```

if the result of the division is 9.99 I would like to show just 9, not 10

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom filter, here's a great answer from: http://tianes.logdown.com/posts/2015/12/08/rounding-a-number-to-the-nearest-neighbour-up-and-down

```
/*********************************************************
    - Author: Sebastian Cubillos
    - Github: @tianes
    - More Gists: https://gist.github.com/tianes/
    - Contact: sebastian@cubillos.org
    - Article: http://tianes.logdown.com/posts/2015/12/08/rounding-a-number-to-the-nearest-neighbour-up-and-down
**********************************************************/

app.filter('round', function () {
    /* Use this $filter to round Numbers UP, DOWN and to his nearest neighbour.
       You can also use multiples */

    /* Usage Examples:
        - Round Nearest: {{ 4.4 | round }} // result is 4
        - Round Up: {{ 4.4 | round:'':'up' }} // result is 5
        - Round Down: {{ 4.6 | round:'':'down' }} // result is 4
        ** Multiples
        - Round by multiples of 10 {{ 5 | round:10 }} // result is 10
        - Round UP by multiples of 10 {{ 4 | round:10:'up' }} // result is 10
        - Round DOWN by multiples of 10 {{ 6 | round:10:'down' }} // result is 0
    */
    return function (value, mult, dir) {
        dir = dir || 'nearest';
        mult = mult || 1;
        value = !value ? 0 : Number(value);
        if (dir === 'up') {
            return Math.ceil(value / mult) * mult;
        } else if (dir === 'down') {
            return Math.floor(value / mult) * mult;
        } else {
            return Math.round(value / mult) * mult;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use javascripts Floor() which will round a number downward to the nearest integer

```
var numb = Math.floor(9.99) // numb = 9
```

Comment: seems like from the syntax and the tags that OP wants to figure out how to do this within AngularJS rather than with vanilla JavaScript.